# How to change location of NFS share without changing autofs configuration

Tags: raid, nfs, autofs

On our data server we currently share a location on an HDD raid /volume1/folder with multiple linux servers via autofs. Every server mounts this location to /data/shared/folder. We now updated to an SSD raid on the same machine and I would like to share /volume2/folder as the new location via NFS.

Is there a way to change something on the data server so that I don't have to update the autofs config of all linux servers? I saw NFS does not resolve server side symbolic links. My idea initially was to move /volume1/folder to /volume2 and then create a symlink from /volume1/folder -> /volume2/folder. This way the autofs would still find the old share. Does anyone have an idea how to make this change as painless as possible?